# How do you create an interactive quicklook plugin thumbnail?

Tags: objective-c, macos, quicklook

I want to create an interactive thumbnail for file type, like the ones that comes with Mac OS X for audio files or PDFs.

I know this is possible but does it involve an undocumented private API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no public API for that.

Answer (score 0):

The only "supported" way to make an interactive QuickLook plug-in is to make an HTML page. Note that you can't use browser plug-ins (like Flash), nor can you pull data from the internet.